# Функция python для определения регистра буквы?

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки

Предположим, есть некая строка x:

```
x = 'AbCdeFghiKlmnopqRSTUvWxyz'
или
x = 'АбВгдеёЖзиКлмнОпрстУфХЦчШЩъЫьЭЮЯ'
```

Я получаю из неё какую-то букву:

```
a = x[i]
```

Как средствами python узнать регистр этой буквы?

Вариант типа

```
def reg1(a):
    if a in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz': return 'нижний'
    elif a in 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ': return 'верхний'
    else: return 'это не буква'
```

не подойдёт, потому что хотелось бы узнать, существует ли встроенная функция python для этой задачи. Если нет встроенной функции, то хотелось бы узнать по крайней мере какое-нибудь изящное однострочное решение.

Comment: `.islower()`- нижний регистр `.isupper()` - верхний

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Встроенные функции python:

```
text = "Hello, World!"

# Проверка на нижний регистр
print(text[0].islower())  # False

# Проверка на верхний регистр
print(text[0].isupper())  # True
```

Comment: Хорошо, а с русскими буквами как?

Comment: `text = "Привет Мир!"`

Comment: Не, я в смысле будет ли работать isupper() с русскими буквами?

Comment: @Глеб Будет, просто попробуйте

Comment: "я в смысле будет ли работать isupper() с русскими буквами?" - а что мешает просто взять и попробовать?